# How to make request using KONG?

Tags: request, kong

When I making a request to Kong using

1)Add API to KONG

```
curl -i -X POST \
--url http://localhost:8001/apis/ \
--data 'name=AnalyticInputHist19api' \ 
--data 'hosts=localhost' \
--data 'upstream_url=http://localhost:9090/AnalyticsInputHistoryController'
```

2)make request using

```
curl -i -X GET \
--url http://localhost:8000/ \
--header 'Host: localhost'
```

It returns me:

`HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Date: Fri, 30 Jun 2017 06:16:03 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Server: kong/0.10.3
An invalid response was received from the upstream server`

kindly help me on how to make successfull request using kong.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1) Add api:

`curl -i -X POST \
      --url http://localhost:8001/apis/ \
      --data 'name=AnalyticsInputHistory' \
      --data 'uris=/API_analytics' \
      --data 'strip_uri=false' \
      --data 'upstream_url=http://10.223.98.66:9090'`

2)Make a request:

`curl -i -X GET http://localhost:8000/API_analytics/AnalyticsInputHistoryController?user=1`

Answer (score 0):

The hosts parameter you used when you created your API doesn’t match the host parameter you used when making your API request.

Comment: Hello @Cooper I made the changes ,still facing the same issue.
 i.e.`An invalid response was received from the upstream server`